# Javafx SceneBuilder Tableview.getSelectionModel not working

Tags: javafx, scenebuilder

Tableview.getSelectionModel not working. After advice form @James_D I have used a Model class (Software) to select columns I need while pulling SQL to a tableview. I searched here, the web, moved code and checked intellisense and the best examples I can find anywhere are commented out in the SoftwareController code below, nothing works?

Prior to using a Model class I had everyting in the `SoftwareController` where EXAMPLE 4 worked, it gave the cell data of column 0 where ever on the row I clicked, which I use to pull more SQL data. This now errors at `newValue.get(0)`, `newValue` is not showing `get()`or getid is available.

I have changed `SelectedItem` to index and added `toString` and all that and I get fxml.software@sometext or the row index. EXAMPLE 1 gives me the cell data of any cell, but I just want the first column on the row I choose, which in my case is an ID, not the row index.
I am also now having to use `@SuppressWarnings` for "Raw" errors, is this because I am in initialize?
Any help or pointers would be appreciated.

SoftwareController

```
public class SoftwareController extends Application implements Initializable {
private Statement statement;
Connection conn = null;
@FXML Button  btnSoftware;
@FXML Label lblTest;
@FXML TableView tblSoftware;
@FXML TableColumn CI_IDcol;
@FXML TableColumn Namecol;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    launch(args);

}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {


    FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/fxml/Software.fxml")); //load Software fxml file
    Parent root1 = (Parent) fxmlLoader.load();
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root1));
    primaryStage.show();

}

private static ObservableList<Software>data;
@FXML   private TextField txtFilter;
private Object getCellData;

@SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })  //added due to TableView getselecionModel code
@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources)  {

    try {

        data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        conn = DBconnection.makeConnection();
        statement = conn.createStatement();
        String SQL = "SELECT * FROM Data_CMDB_Main";
        ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(SQL);

        while (rs.next())   {
            data.add(new Software(rs.getString("CI_ID"),
                                  rs.getString("Name")));

            CI_IDcol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("CI_ID"));
            Namecol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("Name"));
            tblSoftware.setItems(null);
            tblSoftware.setItems(data);

//TableView.selection               
            //get row example 1
            /*tblSoftware.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue observableValue, Object oldValue, Object newValue) {
                if(tblSoftware.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem() != null) {
                    TableViewSelectionModel selectionModel = tblSoftware.getSelectionModel();
                    ObservableList selectedCells = selectionModel.getSelectedCells();
                    TablePosition tablePosition = (TablePosition) selectedCells.get(0);
                    Object val = tablePosition.getTableColumn().getCellData(newValue);
                    //Object val = tblSoftware.getColumns().get(0).toString();
                    System.out.println(val);                    //int row = tablePosition.getRow();

                }                       
                }
            });*/


            //get row example 2   only gives index of filtered rows
            //tblSoftware.getSelectionModel().selectedIndexProperty().addListener((v, oldValue, newValue) -> System.out.println(newValue)); //gets all row data

            //get row example 3 ItemProperty seems correct just not giving readable row identification
            //tblSoftware.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((v, oldValue, newValue) -> System.out.println(newValue)); //gets all row data


            ///get row example 4
            //@Override
            /*tblSoftware.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener( //gets any row column
                    (observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
                        if (newValue == null) {
                            lblTest.setText("");
                            return;
                        }

                        lblTest.setText("Selected Number: " + newValue.get(0)); 
                    }
                );*/

            ///get row example 5

            /*tblSoftware.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener( //gets any row column
                    new ChangeListener<IdentifiedName>() {
                        @Override
                        public void changed (
                            ObservableValue<? extends IdentifiedName> observable,
                            IdentifiedName oldValue,
                            IdentifiedName newValue
                        ){
                            if(newValue == null) {
                                lblTest.setText("");
                                return;
                            }

                        lblTest.setText("Selected Number: " + + newValue.getId(0));

                }
            }   
     );             */



//filter        
            txtFilter.setPromptText("Text Filter");
            txtFilter.textProperty().addListener(new InvalidationListener() {

                @Override
                public void invalidated(Observable o)   {
                    tblSoftware.getSelectionModel().clearSelection(); // this gives no errors when switching back to filter box when row previously selected
                    if(txtFilter.textProperty().get().isEmpty())    {
                        tblSoftware.setItems(data);
                        return;
                    }
                    ObservableList<Software> tableItems = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
                    ObservableList<TableColumn<Software, ?>> cols = tblSoftware.getColumns();
                    for(int i=0; i<data.size(); i++)    {

                    for(int j=0; j<cols.size(); j++)    {
                        TableColumn col = cols.get(j);
                        String cellValue = col.getCellData(data.get(i)).toString();
                        cellValue = cellValue.toLowerCase();
                        if(cellValue.contains(txtFilter.textProperty().get().toLowerCase()))    {
                            tableItems.add(data.get(i));
                            break;                  
                        }
                    }

                    } 
                    tblSoftware.setItems(tableItems);
                }
            });
        }               

    } catch (SQLException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}


protected void setIndex(int selectedIndex) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void btnSoftwarePressed(){
    lblTest.setText("Button works");


}
}
```

Software Class

```
 package fxml;
 import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
 import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;


public class Software {

    private StringProperty CI_ID;
    private StringProperty Name;

    public Software(String CI_ID, String Name)  {
        this.CI_ID = new SimpleStringProperty(CI_ID);
        this.Name = new SimpleStringProperty(Name);
    }

    public StringProperty CI_IDProperty()   {
        return CI_ID;
    }

    public StringProperty NameProperty()    {
        return Name;
    }
}
```

Software fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java .util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>


<BorderPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.40" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="fxml.SoftwareController">
   <center>
      <TableView fx:id="tblSoftware" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="600.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
        <columns>
          <TableColumn fx:id="CI_IDcol" prefWidth="100.0" text="CI_ID" />
          <TableColumn fx:id="Namecol" prefWidth="150.0" text="Name" />
        </columns>
      </TableView>
   </center>
   <top>
      <VBox prefHeight="83.0" prefWidth="600.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <children>
            <HBox prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="200.0">
               <children>
                  <Button fx:id="btnSoftware" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#btnSoftwarePressed" text="Button" />
                  <Label fx:id="lblTest" prefHeight="28.0" prefWidth="158.0" text="Label" />
                  <ParallelCamera />
               </children>
            </HBox>
            <HBox>
               <children>
                  <TextField fx:id="txtFilter" />
               </children>
            </HBox>
         </children>
      </VBox>
   </top>
</BorderPane>
```

Comment: Still unable to get the examples in the controller to work. I don't know enough to correct the issue easily? I just want to select a row and pull data from a column of my choice, regardless of where I click on that row. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure of what you want exactly to do, but I can give you my approach to insert data from db into a tableview, and after that, to get the data from db using the previous data loaded into the tableview.

I first created a inner class inside the controller, which will represent the instances to save in/load from database:

```
public static class Detector {
    private String name;
    private String conn_type;
    private int num_detect;
    private String serial_port;
    private int data_bits;
    private int stop_bits;
    private String parity;
    private String ip;
    private int eth_port;
    private int historic;

    public Detector(String name, String conn_type, int num_detect, String serial_port, int speed,
        int data_bits, int stop_bits, String parity, String ip, int eth_port, int his){

        this.name = name;
        this.conn_type = conn_type;
        this.num_detect = num_detect;
        this.serial_port = serial_port;
        this.data_bits = data_bits;
        this.stop_bits = stop_bits;
        this.parity = parity;
        this.ip = ip;
        this.eth_port = eth_port;
        this.historic = his;
    }
}
```

Afther that, I declared the tableview

```
public class Controller implements Initializable {
   @FXML
   private TableView<Detector> detectors; 
   .
   .
   .
```

And I created the tableview using the data obtained from a query:

```
    DBConnection c = new DBConnection();
    c.connect();
    try{
        String sql = "select * from detector order by name";
        ResultSet rs = c.query(sql);

        ObservableList<Detector> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        while(rs.next()){               
            data.add(new Detector(rs.getString("name"),
                                    rs.getString("conn_type"),                                     
                                    Integer.parseInt(rs.getString("num_detect")),
                                    rs.getString("serial_port"),
                                    Integer.parseInt(rs.getString("speed")),
                                    Integer.parseInt(rs.getString("data_bits")),
                                    Integer.parseInt(rs.getString("stop_bits")),
                                    rs.getString("parity"),
                                    rs.getString("ip"),
                                    Integer.parseInt(rs.getString("puerto_socket")),
                                    Integer.parseInt(rs.getString("historico"))
            ));
        }
        TableColumn colName = new TableColumn("Name");
        colName.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Detector, String>("name"));
        detectors.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> loadName(newValue));
        detectors.setItems(data);
        detectors.getColumns().addAll(nombreCol);           
        //Add a column for every column data you want to show
```

Then, you have to define the behaviour of the method called by the listener (in my case, "loadName")

```
private void loadName(Detector r){
    //here you could, for example, generate a sql query with the data received in r
}
```

Comment: Thanks Juan I will look at that. I basically have a config management database and to keep it simple for now as I learn, i  pull 2 coupthe latest ci_id and name to the tablevie tblSoftware,

Comment: Thanks Juan. I basically have a config management db and for now as I learn, i  pull 2 columns by the date last edited . ci_id and name. So say I pull 2 results to the tableview, first row ci_id 1 : name windows server 1 , second row ci_id 2 : name Linux server 5. So the user wants the history of Linux server 5 and clicks that row. I need the listener to select ci_id or name of that row, pass it to variable, which I can use to run another SQL query to pull all the history of alterations of Linux server 5. it seems to be the getselctionmodel on the tableview not giving the data correctly?

Comment: Also if you look at example 1 commented out in the softwarecontroller, this returns the data coreclty on any cell i click on, if i was able to say just show column ci_id or name that would be the query done.